# How to Merge Name (guest) who has the same Room Number but A different Status

Tags: vba, excel, user-experience

Here is my situation..

I have this file :

```
   1004    Dr  Margarita Solorzano Olabarria    SILVER  228230185    
   1004    Mr  Jose Manuel Santos Aboim Inglez  BRONZE  236338858    
   1007    Mrs  Amanda De Souza Rodrigues       BRONZE  238246729    
   1007    Mr  Eduardo Jaime Smejoff            BRONZE  214046768    
   1010    Mrs  Genevieve Thie                  PLATIN  221093078   
   1010    Mrs  Mary Wilson                     PLPLUS  21384102    
   1203    Ms  Valerie Harrison                 BRONZE  207754414    
   1203    Ms  Joy Bridget Moncrieff            BRONZE  207754415
```

with In Column A : Cabin Number

Column B: Mr or Mrs

Column C: First & Last Name

Column D: Status (bronze, silver etc...)

Column E: Membership number

If Column A are the same I want it on the same row. but it Excludes Status Bronze, Silver,Gold,
So I put this in my VBA to exclude those :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD""),""Delete"", """")"
```

When I run the macros it gaves me this :

```
1211    Mr  Thomas Buettner PLPLUS  Mr  Heinz Juergen Nolte PLPLUS
4011    Mr  Michael Brent   PLATIN  Mrs  Wilhelmina Johanna PLATIN
4013    Mrs  Nancy Jean     PLATIN  Mr  James               PLATIN
4034    Mr  Donald  Meyer   PLATIN  Mrs  Marcia  Meyer      PLATIN
1010    Mrs  Genevieve Thie PLATIN  
1010    Mrs  Mary Wilson    PLPLUS

Column B: Cabin number
Column C: Mr/Mme + Name of guest 1
Column D:Status (Platin, PLPLUS etc..)
Column E : Mr/Mme + Name of Guest 2
Column F: Status
```

Look at the Number 1010..

Somehow Both are in the condition but because they have different status, the macro put them in a different row and I don't want that, I want them in the same row..

I want this :

```
1211    Mr  Thomas Buettner PLPLUS  Mr  Heinz Juergen Nolte PLPLUS
4011    Mr  Michael Brent   PLATIN  Mrs  Wilhelmina Johanna PLATIN
4013    Mrs  Nancy Jean     PLATIN  Mr  James               PLATIN
4034    Mr  Donald  Meyer   PLATIN  Mrs  Marcia  Meyer      PLATIN
1010    Mrs  Genevieve Thie PLATIN  Mrs  Mary Wilson        PLPLUS
```

Here is my Code for this sheets called "ChocoStrawb".

```
  ' Chocolate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "ChocoStrawb"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Rows("2:4200").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:O4200")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select
```

Here is my whole Code :

```
Sub LATDownloadMACROS()
'
' LATDownloadMACROS Macro
' Macro recorded 02/25/2017 by Johan Esteve


' Debut Macro
Cells.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C:C").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[-3])&"" ""&PROPER(RC[-1])&"" ""&PROPER(RC[-2])"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E4200").Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("B18").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Download"
Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 1"
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level1"
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 2"
Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level2"
Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 3"
Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level3"
Range("F1:G1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F1:M1"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 2"
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=R[-1]C[-3],RC[-2],"""")"
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=R[-1]C[-4],RC[-2],"""")"
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C[-3]=RC[-3],R[1]C[-2],"""")"
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C[-4]=RC[-4],R[1]C[-2],"""")"
Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[2]C[-5]=RC[-5],R[2]C[-4],"""")"
Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[2]C[-6]=RC[-6],R[2]C[-4],"""")"
Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[3]C[-7]=RC[-7],R[3]C[-6],"""")"
Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[3]C[-8]=RC[-8],R[3]C[-6],"""")"
Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[4]C[-9]=RC[-9],R[4]C[-8],"""")"
Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[4]C[-10]=RC[-10],R[4]C[-8],"""")"
Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[5]C[-11]=RC[-11],R[5]C[-10],"""")"
Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[5]C[-12]=RC[-12],R[5]C[-10],"""")"
Range("D2:M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:M4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D2:M4200").Select

Columns("D:M").AutoFit
Sheets("Sheet2").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Range("D2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Columns("D:M").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Columns("A:A").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Columns("A:C").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("A2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=if"
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""BRONZE"",RC[3]=""SILVER""),""Delete"","""")"

Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Sheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Move After:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Champagne"
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Name = "Water"
Columns("E:N").Copy

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D2").Select
Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Sheets("Download").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("A:C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Ambassador
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("A2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Ambassador"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Rows("2:4200").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:O4200")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select

' Chocolate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "ChocoStrawb"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Rows("2:4200").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:O4200")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select


' PlatinumPlus
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "PlatPlus"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Platinum
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "Platinum"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Gold
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C6").Select
Range("C496:C4288").Select
Range("C4288:C16").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Name = "Gold"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Rajout
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Silver

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C13").Select
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C7").Select
Sheets("Gold").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "Silver"
Sheets("Silver").Select
Sheets("Silver").Copy Before:=Sheets(6)
Sheets("Silver").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""PLATIN"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

' Bronze

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Columns("B:D").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""PLATIN"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A519"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A519").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False _
    , Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

' Nomage C1
Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Gold").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Silver").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Nomage Bronze
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Sheets("Silver (2)").Name = "Bronze"
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A1").Select

' Filtre et Figer
Sheets("Champagne").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Silver").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Bronze").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Gold").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

' Color
Sheets("Champagne").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Champagne").Tab.ColorIndex = 6
Sheets("Platinum").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Platinum").Tab.ColorIndex = 16
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PlatPlus").Tab.ColorIndex = 55
Sheets("Silver").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silver").Tab.ColorIndex = 15
Sheets("Bronze").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bronze").Tab.ColorIndex = 9
Sheets("Gold").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Gold").Tab.ColorIndex = 43
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Tab.ColorIndex = 3
Sheets("Water").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Water").Tab.ColorIndex = 2
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ambassador").Tab.ColorIndex = 1
Sheets("Download").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Download").Tab.ColorIndex = 4

' Delete

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For x = 4200 To 2 Step -1
    If WS.Cells(x, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
        WS.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
Next WS


' Formulas

Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(D2:N2)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""GOLD"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLATIN""))*1)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLPLUS"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""AMBASS""))*2)"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"
Dim LRowA As String, LRowB As String
LRowA = [A4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "B").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & LastRow & ")"
LRowA = [B4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("B:B").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("B2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "B").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & LastRow & ")"
LRowA = [B4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("B:B").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("B2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


' Classement Onglets
Sheets("Water").Select
Sheets("Water").Move Before:=Sheets(2)
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Move Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Bronze").Select
Sheets("Bronze").Move Before:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Silver").Select
Sheets("Silver").Move Before:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("Gold").Select
Sheets("Gold").Move Before:=Sheets(6)
Sheets("Champagne").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to follow exactly (based on your examples) where the breakdown is happening.  In the initial example, you show that 1010 has a duplicate, as do others, then in the second example you don't show the same data (only 1010 shows up as a duplicate).  I would have expected 1004 duplicates to be moved up to see what's all going on, which is in the first example, but not in the second.

Assuming I follow, I would recommend keeping your sorting, then instead of using a activecell.formula to determine what gets moved where, just use VBA.  Loop through and determine what lines are the same, then move the items you need the same; after cut/paste, delete the row.

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 3 to 4200 '4200 taken from your range.  starting at 3 because range starts at 2 (i-1)

    If Cells(i-1,1).Value=Cells(i,1).Value Then
        Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i,4)).Cut Range(Cells(i-1,5),Cells(i-1,7))
        Row(i).Delete
    End If

Next i
```

Edit:

You should be able to shorten up your sorting, too:

```
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Range("A1:H4200).Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Essentially your whole code to sort through your sheet, move people sharing a cabin. then delete empty rows, would look like this:

```
Dim i as Integer

Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Range("A1:H4200).Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

For i = 3 to 4200 '4200 taken from your range.  starting at 3 because range starts at 2 (i-1)

With Sheets("ChocoStrawb")

    If .Cells(i-1,1).Value=.Cells(i,1).Value Then
        .Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i,4)).Cut .Range(Cells(i-1,5),Cells(i-1,7))
        .Row(i).Delete
    End If

End With

Next i
```

That should be an overall improvement.  Try to avoid select/activate in your coding, as it complicates the steps.

Comment: I understand your point about my sorry it is because I did a copy paste from a large list of cabin number.. do you want me to Re Edit my post to be more clear or not ...

Comment: @JohanEs if what i listed answers your question, then no need.  Just accept if it solves for you and we're solid, otherwise let me know if you edit so i can get a more clear understanding of the problem and try to help.

Comment: I was working with your code but it is saying Missing Next without For when I copy paste what you wrote... I don't understand why....

Comment: I believe it may be tied to my With statement not having an End With.  Just put one in, before the Next i.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution using the Windows Jet/ACE SQL engine. Two things though are required: 1) use Excel for Windows and 2) add column names as top header of data. Below assumes data resides in a tab named *DATA* and an existing tab named *RESULTS* to hold SQL results. Two connection types are included.

```
Public Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' DRIVER AND PROVIDER CONNECTION TYPES
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = " SELECT t1.[CabinNumber], t1.[Mr./Mrs.], t1.[First & Last Name], t1.Status, " _
                & "   t2.[Mr./Mrs.], t2.[First & Last Name], t2.Status" _
                & " FROM [DATA$] t1 INNER JOIN [DATA$A] t2" _
                & " ON t1.[CabinNumber] = t2.[CabinNumber]" _
                & " WHERE NOT t1.Status IN ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze')"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i    

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    ' CLOSE OBJECTS AND FREE RESOURCES
    rst.Close: conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```